# Getting a list of partials actually used in handlebars template compile

Tags: node.js, templates, handlebars.js

I am attempting to pull a list of partials *actually* used during a handlebars template compile. It would be even more ideal if I could get that info before the actual compile somehow.

Below is a simple example of handlebars compiling the way you'd expect:

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');

var template = `
    Template: {{>a}}
`;

handlebars.registerPartial('a', `
    Partial A: {{A}} {{>b}}
`);
handlebars.registerPartial('b', `
    Partial B: {{B}} {{>c}}
`);
handlebars.registerPartial('c', `
    Partial C: {{C}}
`);
handlebars.registerPartial('d', `
    Partial D: {{D}}
`);

var compiled = handlebars.compile(template);

console.log(compiled({
    'A' : 'A is for Apple',
    'B' : 'B is for Ball',
    'C' : 'C is for Cat',
    'D' : 'Not used'
}));
```

The output being

```
Template:
Partial A: A is for Apple
Partial B: B is for Ball
Partial C: C is for Cat
```

I would like to have is a list that returns the fact that partials A, B, and C were actually used during the compile.

What I'm trying to avoid here is writing my own regex to parse the template and then manually build that list. I would prefer if I could stick to the mechanism that is actually used in handlebars to avoid potential future breakages.

Comment: Good feature request. Would love that!

Comment: @Fabian it is already possible - see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you execute your compiled template, any partials that have been used become functions within the Handlebars object. Unused partials will remain strings.

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars')

var template = `
    Template: {{>a}}
`

handlebars.registerPartial('a', `
    Partial A: {{A}} {{>b}}
`)
handlebars.registerPartial('b', `
    Partial B: {{B}} {{>c}}
`)
handlebars.registerPartial('c', `
    Partial C: {{C}}
`)
handlebars.registerPartial('d', `
    Partial D: {{D}}
`)

var compiled = handlebars.compile(template)

compiled({})

var used = []
var unused = []

for (var name in handlebars.partials) {
  var partial = handlebars.partials[name]
  if (typeof partial === 'function') {
    used.push(name)
  } else {
    unused.push(name)
  }
}

console.log('Used partials: ' + used) // a,b,c

console.log('Unused partials: ' + unused) // d
```